# Bin Bash file not found

Tags: php, bash

i'm really beginner with SH Scripts.

I found a small sh script that convert a php file with wget to html. I would like to do a small cronjob with it. But everytime i run that script i get the message (Translated) "Defect Interpreter" > File or folder not Found".

My script is only

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf header-wrapper.html && wget http://master.gnetwork.eu/header-wrapper.php -O header-wrapper.html -q
```

Comment: Sounds like `bash` isn't installed. Unless it requires any fance features, `/bin/sh` is the better option. Figure out what distro your server is running with.

Comment: If you do `which bash` does it find it and if so is it in `/bin`?  Sometimes it could be installed in a spot like `/usr/bin` or somewhere other than `/bin`.

Comment: Hi, bash is installed, other SH Scripts are running with it without issues. I tried bin SH, same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that your *shebang* is wrong (`bash` executable is not found at `/bin/bash` when cron job starts).

From your cron job, use `bash` explicitly when calling the script:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

instead of:

```
./myscript.sh
```

Also, do not make any assumptions on the working directory of the cron job. Change the directory in your bash script before doing anything else

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/desired/path && \
rm -rf header-wrapper.html && \
wget http://master.gnetwork.eu/header-wrapper.php -O header-wrapper.html -q
```

Comment: Wow thank you :) this is working. You saved my day *give a virtual Beer* *highfive*

Comment: Ah yust one question more. If i repeat that command it is giving out. "render.sh: Row 3: $'\r': Command not found." what can this mean? Its working but giving this message out

Comment: Go to the path where `render.sh` is located and call manually `tr -cd "\r" < render.sh | wc -c`. What is the output?

Comment: I suspect the script has DOS-style endings. Just try `dos2unix render.sh`

Comment: Update: With dos2unix i now can run it as bin sh :) thank you so much a further time :)

Comment: In fact, I would say you *must* assume that the cron job is running somewhere other than your script's location unless it's at your ~ since cron runs from the crontab owner's directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing Bash in before the filename.

```
bash [File Name Here]
```

instead of

```
.[File Name Here]
```

Sorry if someone else already answered this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this too, if you use Windows line ending CR/LF instead of Linux line ending LF.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).